# What is the purpose of static final variables in annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm learning Java and want to know **Why can annotations contain static final variables? What do they do?**

Thanks.

Comment: They're constants just like on any other type, and they're used for the same reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Final**  means that the variable will not be changed.
`final int x=45;`

> here the value of x will be final and will not be changed.

**Static** means that the variable it is a class variable.Which can be accessed through the class name.
`static y=34;`

> y will be accessible by class name like ClassA.y, where ClassA is the name of the class of which y is a static variable

**AND** you can use final static in annotations because they are constants(compile time)